# Calling Objective-C viewcontroller from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, jqplot

I am using jqplot (JavaScript library) for charting in my iPhone application. I can load pie-chart on webview successfully. But I want to call Objective-C viewcontroller based on value changes in JavaScript (value will be changed when on-click event fired on the different portion of the pie-chart). I don't know how to do that. Please tell me how to go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Just about the only method for communication from Javascript to Objective-C is to set a special URL in `window.location` and detect that URL in the `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` method in your UIWebView delegate.